# Lost my localhost directory

Tags: php, apache

Previously when i ran 'http:/localhost/' could take me direct to my xampp homepage.

I followed a tutorial to create a virtual host and also edit the hosts file.

my windows32 hosts file looks like this

```
>   127.0.0.1       localhost
>   127.0.0.1       my_test_server
>   #   ::1             localhost
```

my  xammp httpd-vhosts.conf was editeed with these additions

```
> <VirtualHost *:80>   
>     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my_test_server/public"
>     ServerName my_test_server
> </VirtualHost>
```

now this is fine when i browse with

> http://my_test_server/videos

but when i browse

http://localhost
i dont get back the xampp index page. so i cant create a mysql db
any help ?

Comment: what happens when you go to my_test_server?

Comment: I get the videos

Comment: My probem is that localhost nolonger points to xammp index page

Comment: You should be able to create another `VirtualHost` entry with a localhost server name to your xampp htdocs.

Comment: Thank you so much xander

Comment: it woked very well :D

Comment: good, I can write it as an answer so you can accept it. I also found out some other trick. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create another `VirtualHost` entry with a localhost server name to your xampp htdocs directory.

Also if you look at the example in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file it says:

> The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
>   match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any  block.

so you may also be able to just write this as the first `VirtualHost` (without a server name)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
```